# Css background colour not working

Tags: html, css

Hello I am creating a website and I can't 
here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img src=images\cat.gif></img>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">
          <p id="output"><b>Likes: 0</b> 
          </p>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">
          <button class="button" onclick="likeButton()">Like</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have now idea what is wrong all of the guides I've seen have fixed syntax errors but I've triple checked and I am almost sure I don't have any plus on other documents I have the same issue. I may just be bad. Thanks...

Comment: use # before fff (#fff)

Comment: as @Friend stated you need to use # before hex colors as you are obviously trying to use hex colors here.

Comment: you have missed a `#` before `ffffff`

Comment: This is a question to close as typographycal error (offtopic on stackoverflow). Why 9 answers? Not neccessary. `#` is basic html/css development.

Answer (score 3):

```
 body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Try This

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

in body css , there's missing #(hash) symbol before color code, 
 below code may work.

```
 body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

here is jsfiddle link , you can check here too, it's working  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/mjpdy95z/1/)

and reason behind image not displaying is that , you did not double quote src value. like `src="images\cat.gif"`

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
background-color: #ffffff;
overflow: auto;
}
```

First You Learn Css

if  you forgot to put # symbol in front of color code,css does not apply to it ,and `#ffffff` color RGB value is `(255,255,255)`. This hex color code is also a web safe color which is equal to `#FFF`. `#ffffff` color name is White color.

Comment: to give good answer, mention why he did not get proper result, and explain code if possible

Comment: that is why i have given the answer , or you giving  a suggestion or asking the question to me MR.yash ..if So ,he has removed # symbol in front  of color code,css does't apply it ,and #ffffff color RGB value is (255,255,255). This hex color code is also a web safe color which is equal to #FFF. #ffffff color name is White color. ,if you know more than this kindly explain ,,,!!!i will also learn from you !

Comment: whatever you written in previous comment, better if you edit add it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

CSS changes:

```
     body {        
    background-color:#ffffff;       
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

As `#FFFFFF` is white color. so you will not see it so change color and check

```css
body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #FF0000;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <img src=images\cat.gif></img>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left;"><p id="output"><b>Likes: 0</b>        </p></th>
                <th style="text-align:right;"><button class="button" onclick="likeButton()">Like</button></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing write "#" in front of background color code. eg:`#ffffff`
Second thing `#ffffff` this color code is for white color if want see the difference, please change this color code to `#FF0000`

```
body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #ffffff;   // white color    please replace this to "#FF0000"  inoder to see the difference 
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed # in `background-color: ffffff`;
correct it by adding # like

`background-color: #ffffff`;

white is by default background color of browser. you can test it by changing with `#ffbf00`, `#4000ff` etc

Recommended read it from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Answer (score 1):

'#' is missing in your code. If you setting background-color anywhere else use '!important'

```
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no compulsory rule to put # symbol before on color .In this, Kane's code is correct.But **background-color: ffffff**;return **white color**.ie.**ffffff** means **white color**. So we can not find any background in the website.If you have any doubt you change your background -color as *background-color: FF0000;* then you can clear your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete `</img>`  and add `"` in src
Please have a look to this: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/MaciejWojcik/b8sjaxzv/)